# golang and ListenAndServeTLS return error

Tags: http, go

```
func main(){
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    www := r.Host("secure.domain.com").Subrouter()
    www.HandleFunc("/", Handler_www)

    api := r.Host("api.domain.com").Subrouter()
    api.HandleFunc("/", Handler_api)

    go func(){
        cert := "/var/ini/ssl/secure.domain.com/intermediate.crt"
        prv_key := "/var/ini/ssl/secure.domain.com/private.key"
        err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":9443", cert, prv_key, r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("HTTPS server: ", err)
        }
    }

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("HTTP server: ", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and add `()` after the closing `}`.

That way, you would actually call the `func()`.

```
go func(){
    cert := "/var/ini/ssl/secure.domain.com/intermediate.crt"
    prv_key := "/var/ini/ssl/secure.domain.com/private.key"
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":9443", cert, prv_key, r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("HTTPS server: ", err)
    }
}()
```

Comment: This works, but now I get this error `server: crypto/tls: private key does not match public key`

Comment: @clarkk I see the error emitted from here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/tls.go#L219-L249. Make sure the format used for the certificate and the key are the same (pem).

Comment: @clarkk please don't change the question: I have answered the *original* question.